# SQL Server 2012 AVG statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue trying to use a certain statement and I did EXACTLY what I saw on `youtube` and I still get it incorrect. Here is my issue

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) AS Average_Salary FROM Employee;

Error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.
```

I did the exact same thing and still got it wrong, but in the `youtube video` it was correct.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: First, you shouldn't be storing numeric values in a string column.  Second, SQL Server will attempt the conversion, so you must have some bad values.  Third, you should include sample data and desired results in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your data is not clean or it is formatted incorrectly.

  `SELECT SALARY
   FROM dbo.Employee 
   WHERE ISNUMERIC(Salary) = 1`

likely you will find your salaries include the ( , ) in your numbers, which cannot be converted into a numeric integer by implicit conversions.

SQL Server is smart, but it must follow precedence of conversion. Trying to implicitly convert a non-numeric varchar into an integer is often considered an illegal conversion. AVG takes an [explicit numeric](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx&ved=0ahUKEwiE7Lfx2abOAhVq5IMKHfBxCE8QFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNFtgi1LuVaFxlxX4DBc_TRkpOhulg&sig2=IpDBeu681kQLUXdHYGWhPg) value, so trying to implicitly convert a string would cause the function to lose information (which it cannot do implicitly).

Instead, convert the value into a data type that can be flexible with non-numeric values such as

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(Salary AS MONEY)) as SALARY_AVG
FROM Employees
```

For a better understanding of implicit conversions and the limitations, see [DATA TYPE CONVERSIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: When in doubt, check the function from MSDN

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is pretty clear.  You can use `try_convert()` to convert the values to a number:

```
SELECT AVG(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), Salary)) AS Average_Salary
FROM Employee;
```